# pycurl login bad request?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pycurl

I chose not to use requests because its slower. anyways i think im missing some csrf or cookies token as im trying to login to instagram. The problem with pycurl is it doesnt show the reason for the bad requests.
this is my code
[heres it in photo mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNv8X.png)

````
def swap():
    buffer = StringIO()
    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher")
    curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, useragent)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, payload)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDSIZE, len(payload))
    curl.perform()
    curl.close()

    body = buffer.getvalue()
    print(body)```
````

Answer (score 1):

You would need to get the error or http status to find out the reason.

`pycurl.error` should help, check this [link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/5253/pycurl.error) for more information